# Disabling active selection in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

Since yesterday I found that I can select every textual content in Firefox! In fact, some of them should not be selectable in a normal condition, such as the case in the following figure.
[Look at the cursor!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gXa7.png)

So, what is wrong with it and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are in caret-mode, where you can select text with the keyboard.

Press F7 to disable.

Pressing F7 enables it again (there you should have seen a info/warning message)

Comment: Thanks for your life-saving solution. I'm not able to upvote, by the way!

Comment: @84374g I provided an upvote for the answer for you.  I also gave your question an upvote because it's a good question and to help you be able to upvote in the future. :)